# Is there a major difference between "einstellen" and "verstellen"?

Tags: meaning, difference, german-to-english

I was wondering where the difference lies between *einstellen* and *verstellen* in terms of "adjusting" something. For example, what are the differences between:

> 1. Ich muss meine Uhr einstellen.
> 2. Ich muss meine Uhr verstellen.

My sense is that the first sentence means *to generally set / adjust*, while the second means *to adjust from its original place*, or *to change it from where it was*. Is this correct?

Answer (score 8):

Spricht man von Geräten, so ist *einstellen* das Anpassen des Geräts in Richtung Genauigkeit oder erwünschter Funktionsweise, während *verstellen* das Ändern in Richtung Ungenauigkeit oder unerwünschter Funktionsweise bezeichnet.

Speziell bei einer Uhr im Alltagsgebrauch würde man jedoch eher sagen "die Uhr stellen", nicht "die Uhr einstellen".

> Mutter hat die Küchenuhr gestellt.

(Gewöhnliche Uhr; es geht um die Anzeige der richtigen Uhrzeit)

> Der Physiker hat die Atomuhr **ein**gestellt.

(Kompliziertes Gerät; es geht auch nicht so sehr um die Anzeige der richtigen Uhrzeit, eher um die korrekte Funktion im allgemeinen.)

Hier weitere Beispiele typischer Verwendung:

> Die Uhr ist verstellt.
>
> Du solltest mal deine Uhr stellen!
>
> Das Potentiometer ist sehr genau eingestellt.
>
> Können Sie den Motor meines Diesel-Autos so einstellen, dass weniger Stickoxide entstehen?
>
> Oha! Schon wieder Winterzeit! Ich muss die Uhr **um**stellen.

(Dies speziell beim Umstellen von Sommer- und Winterzeit. Siehe Roberts Kommentar unten)

> Der Patient ist gut eingestellt.

(Mediziner-Jargon für Patienten, für die durch Versuch und Irrtum die richtige Dosierung eines Medikaments gefunden wurde.)

---

*Verstellen* hat daneben noch andere Bedeutungen und Einsatzmöglichkeiten.

> Geh mal bitte beiseite, du verstellst mir die Sicht!

(etwas so plazieren, dass es die freie Sicht stört)

> Er fand den Auftritt des Direktors zum Schreien komisch, aber er hat sich gut verstellt und hat sich nichts anmerken lassen.

(seine wahren Gefühle oder Absichten verbergen)

> Lass uns mal das Regal verstellen, damit ich dahinter saubermachen kann.

Dies ist im Sinne einer Positionsänderung im Raum, wie du in der Frage ja auch für die Uhr vermutet hast. Theoretisch könnte man wohl auch in diesem Sinne *eine Uhr verstellen*, aber dann müsste es schon ein große, schwere Standuhr sein.

---

Ebenso *einstellen*:

> Wir möchten Sie als Krankenschwester einstellen.

(jemanden engagieren, unter Vertrag nehmen)

> Können Sie das bitte einstellen? Das stört!

(etwas bleiben lassen; aufhören zu tun)

Comment: Der Vollständigkeit halber könntest du noch "sich auf etw. einstellen" im Sinne von vorbereiten aufnehmen.

Answer (score 5):

To me, "verstellen" sounds much more negative, as changing something to a poor setting. This may be without knowing what you're doing, or even with malicious intent.

> Das Fernsehbild ist ganz verrieselt! Wer hat schon wieder die Antenne verstellt?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your understanding is basically correct.

"Einstellen" means to set/configure something - the implication usually being that the resulting configuration is correct/as desired afterwards.

"Verstellen" just means to alter an existing configuration. Whether or not the resulting configuration is correct can only be deduced from context, but it usually implies that the speaker is of the opinion that the new setting is incorrect or worse than the previous one. This word is frequently used when one person complains about someone else changing a setting.

For setting the time on a clock from one previously correct setting to a new correct setting, as for example due to daylight saving or traveling across time zone boundaries, the most idiomatic term would be "umstellen".